# Sistema de usuarios basado en seguidores

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos tengo un sistema de usuarios similar al de instagram donde se puede seguir y dejar de seguir a otro usuario, pero como en toda red social existe una sección de sugerencias o personas que quizás conozcas y allí es donde necesito la ayuda ya que necesito sacar de esta sección los usuarios que ya siguen al usuario que se encuentra en sección ya que principalmente tengo un query que muestra todos los usuarios registrados en la plataforma y pues para que mostrar en este apartado los que ya siguen al usuario entonces necesito sacarlos de la lista, tengo la siguiente estructura.

Con este query muestro todos los usuarios que se encuentran registrados y el rol que cumplen dentro de la plataforma.

```
SELECT * from usuario inner join rol on usuario.rol = rol.idrol
```

Probé con este query pero no me muestra ningún resultado, con el campo de y para logro saber de quien fue y a quien le envió solicitud el usuario

```
SELECT * from
 usuario inner join rol on usuario.rol = rol.idrol inner join amigo on 
 amigo.idamigo = usuario.idusuario where
 amigo.de = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."' and estado = '1' or amigo.para = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."' and estado = '1'
```

en este query muestro el numero de seguidores que tiene el usuario que se encuentra en sesión que son los que necesito sacar del listado del query de mas arriba

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(de) total FROM amigo WHERE para = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."' AND estado = '1'
```

Comment: Pone parentesis en tu query separando las partes que queres y vas a ver que funciona... supongo que es (amigo de and estado) or (lo otro)

Comment: igual estado no tiene mucho sentido que este dos veces no?

Comment: @gbianchi sigue sin mostrarme resultados

Comment: Bueno.. eso es imposible que lo sepamos sin conocer la estructura de las tablas y los datos... tal vez no hay nada que mostrar....

Comment: me muestra todos los usuarios registrados incluyendo los que me siguen como lo mencione anteriormente pero de esa lista necesito sacar los que ya me siguen porque para que los voy a volver a mostrar seria redundante @gbianchi

Comment: Bueno.. yo por lo menos, sin mas informacion, no puedo ayudarte.. no se que datos tiene cada tabla, ni como se relacionan...

Answer (score 1):

Pon parentesis entr los ands y ors o quieta condiciones sobrantes

Saludos

```sql
  SELECT * from
 usuario inner join rol on usuario.rol = rol.idrol inner join amigo on 
 amigo.idamigo = usuario.idusuario where
 (amigo.de = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."' and estado = '1') or (amigo.para = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."' and estado = '1' )
```